# Помощь с составлением регулярного выражения

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

При парсинге необходимо вытащить один из параметров, которого нет на странице,
но оно есть в js.

Кусок Js

```
i","brandId":14426,"nomenclatures":{"2217416":{"cod1S":2217416,"ordersCount":700,"artikul":"
```

Необходимо вытащить значение в ordersCount

Я сначала пытался вытащить 2 index поиска text.find() и потом вырезать из текста, но он выкидывало -1, т.е не найдено

Сейчас пытаюсь c помощью регулярки, но возникла проблема с составлением ее.
Не могу понять, как ограничить слева и справа.

Последняя попытка `/^"ordersCount":.\$/`

Comment: что именно ограничить? значение идет в таком порядке, или есть вариации?

Comment: ^ - это начало строки, $ - это конец строки. Слэши зачем вообще. Какой это диалект? Почему не так https://regex101.com/r/0Iyi2j/1?

Comment: @mrEvgenX ну а как само значение 700 получить?

Comment: @finally получить текст, ограниченный слева "ordersCount":  и права ближайшей запятой

Comment: `\"ordersCount\":\s*(.+),`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так, только следите за типом кавычек (в примере для двойной кавычки):

```
import re
s = 'i","brandId":14426,"nomenclatures":{"2217416":{"cod1S":2217416,"ordersCount":700,"artikul":"'
r = re.findall(r'\"ordersCount\":(\d+)', s)
print(r)
```

Comment: Вы ищите сам текст, а мне нужно само значение 700 получить.
Я могу конечно, сделать print(r[r.find(":"):] и вывести 700, но нельзя это с помощью регулярки?

Comment: `r.group(1)` в помощь

Comment: Метод `"findall"` вам как раз в список и вытянет все значения. Или, если используете `"search"` - выводите через `".group()"`, как предложил товарищ выше.